# Character converted into string is printing strange values C++

Tags: c++, string

I am getting a character which is in array form and then i am converting it into string. If i am printing it in string form, it is printing strange things after printing the required character.

```
char array[2];

array[0] = 'A';
array[1] = 'B';

string name( array );
cout<<"In string format: "<<name;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The array is not null terminated, you should do this:

```
char array[3];
array[0] = 'A';
array[1] = 'B';
array[2] = 0;
```

This is due to many string routines using character encoding like null to determine where the end of a string is. It is counterintuitive yes and the cause of many problems. I suggest always using an std::string rather than directly manipulating character arrays.

Answer (score 6):

your string is not [null-terminated string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string). try this

```
char array[3];

array[0] = 'A';
array[1] = 'B';
array[2] = '\0'; // this indicate that the string end here

string name( array );
cout<<"In string format: "<<name;
```

Answer (score 1):

an array is a pointer.  When you say string name(array), you are passing in the literal address in memory to the location of array.
The program will read from that pointer location until it reads a null character which could be anywhere in memory unless you put it in.